# How is $\frac{(10^{4})^{6}-1}{10^4-1} = 1 + 10^{4} + 10^{8} + 10^{12} + 10^{16} + 10^{20}$?

Tags: fractions

As the title states, how is: $$\frac{(10^{4})^{6}-1}{10^4-1} = 1 + 10^{4} + 10^{8} + 10^{12} + 10^{16} + 10^{20}$$

I can't see the pattern. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: try setting $a=10^4$ and rewrite the expression

Comment: Have you ever seen the identity $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}=1+q^1+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1}$. It's not hard to prove really it's just polynomial long division.

Comment: I have never seen that identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x\not=1$,
$$(x-1)(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^6-1$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x^6-1}{x-1}=x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general that $x^6-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^5)$.  Just substitute $x=10^4$.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes from the algebraic identity:
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1).$$